# Email attachment not opening after sending successfully from smtp server mvc 5

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc-5, smtpclient

After sending file using ajax in formdata to controller i am sending email with attachment. Email send successfully but when i open that email to view in my email account so email is attached but not opening showing error msg

**There was a problem displaying this image**

```
List < HttpPostedFileBase > attachments = new List<HttpPostedFileBase>();
HttpPostedFileBase frontimage = null;
foreach(string fileName in Request.Files)
{
    frontimage = Request.Files["frontimage"];
}

attachments.Add(frontimage);
using(MailMessage mm = new MailMessage("example@gmail.com", "example2@hotmail.com"))
{
    mm.Subject = "Test Email";
    mm.Body = "test";

    foreach(HttpPostedFileBase attachment in attachments)
    {
        if (attachment != null) {
            string fileName = Path.GetFileName(attachment.FileName);
            mm.Attachments.Add(new Attachment(attachment.InputStream, fileName));
        }
    }
    mm.IsBodyHtml = false;
    SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient();
    smtp.Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
    smtp.EnableSsl = true;
    NetworkCredential NetworkCred = new NetworkCredential("username", "password");
    smtp.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
    smtp.Credentials = NetworkCred;
    smtp.Port = 587;
    smtp.Send(mm);

}
```

Comment: The image displaying problem sounds related to content type or attachment setting when using `MailMessage`. Did you tried with some different images that have different sizes?

Comment: i have tried pdf , jpg, xd format they all are not opening

Answer (score 0):

Solved by adding attachment.InputStream.Position = 0;